# AWS data pipeline skips remote JAR in S3

Tags: amazon-data-pipeline

I have a AWS data pipeline in which I am trying to execute a step whose code is in a JAR located in an S3 bucket. I specify the path and the class name but the pipeline logs read "Warning: Skip remote jar" and my code never executes. The body of my step is:

`command-runner.jar,spark-submit,--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn,--class,com.myorg.myapp.MyClass,s3://MyBucket/my-jar.jar,myArg`

Now, in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-emractivity.html) it appears that I can run code in a remote jar but it doesn't seems to be the case? Anyone experienced this and has made this work?

Answer (score 0):

I did it as follows:

I specified the path of the jar as `{input.directoryPath}/SWALiveOrderModelSpark-1.0-super.jar`,
where the input.directoryPath comes from using the `S3DataNode`.